# PHP - keep internal pointer after foreach() on Iterator object

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, iterator

Below are the codes from PHP doc about [Iterator](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) with a few lines added to show the position.

As you can see, The object has 3 elements, and the position is at the 2nd element ($this->position=1) before the foreach(),

After foreach(), position is changed to an invalid value ($this->position=3).

```
class myIterator implements Iterator {
    private $position = 0;
    private $array = array(
        "firstelement",
        "secondelement",
        "lastelement",
    );  

    public function __construct() {
        $this->position = 0;
    }

    public function rewind() {
        var_dump(__METHOD__);
        $this->position = 0;
    }

    public function current() {
        var_dump(__METHOD__);
        return $this->array[$this->position];
    }

    public function key() {
        var_dump(__METHOD__);
        return $this->position;
    }

    public function next() {
        var_dump(__METHOD__);
        ++$this->position;
    }

    public function valid() {
        var_dump(__METHOD__);
        return isset($this->array[$this->position]);
    }

    public function showPosition() {
        return $this->position;
    }

}

$it = new myIterator;

$it->next(); 
var_dump($it->showPosition());   //shows 1

foreach($it as $key => $value) {
    var_dump($key, $value);
    echo "\n"; }

var_dump($it->showPosition()); //shows 3 which is an invalid value.
```

In the [foreach() doccument](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)  it shows:

> Note: In PHP 5, .... . In PHP 7, foreach does not use the internal array pointer.

I'm using PHP7, and obviously the above sample codes show that the internal point does changed after foreach().

My question is - is it possible to keep the original position after foreach()?

I understand one possible way is to add a variable to remember the position before foreach() and after foreach(), set the position manually. But it seems contradicting to what the foreach() doc suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pointer in your implimentation of the Itterator is incorrect after the loop, because you are not setting/resetting the value on the last call to `valid()` from the foreach loop it retains the last incrented value which is outside of the array bounds ( in this case `3` ), the easiest thing to do here is set the pointer `null` so it reflects the behavior of PHP, ( what you get when using the native array functions inside an iterator, more on that later )

One thing to note, as you pointed out there is a change in PHP7

> Note: In PHP 5, when foreach first starts executing, the internal
>   array pointer is automatically reset to the first element of the
>   array. This means that you do not need to call reset() before a
>   foreach loop. As foreach relies on the internal array pointer in PHP
>   5, changing it within the loop may lead to unexpected behavior. In PHP
>   7, foreach does not use the internal array pointer.

Personally I don't see this as a big issue, unless you relay on the internal pointer.  Which in my experience just doesn't happen much.

Now to fix your implementation of Iterator:

Option 1:

Let PHP handle tracking the pointer by using the native array functions:

```
class myIterator implements Iterator {

    private $array = array(
        "firstelement",
        "secondelement",
        "lastelement",
    );  

    public function __construct() {
        reset( $this->array );
    }

    public function rewind() {
        reset( $this->array );
    }

    public function current() {
        return current( $this->array );
    }

    public function key() {
       return key( $this->array );
    }

    public function next() {
       next( $this->array );
    }

    public function valid() {
        return isset( $this->array[$this->key()] );
    }

    //alias of key()
    public function showPosition() {
        return $this->key();
    }
}


echo str_pad('= NATIVE TRACKED POINTER =', 60, '=') ."\n";

$it = new myIterator;

$it->next(); //move to index 1

var_dump($it->key());   //<-- should print 1

foreach($it as $key => $value) {}

var_dump($it->key()); //<--shows NULL,

echo str_pad('= NATIVE ARRAY POINTER =', 60, '=') ."\n";

$array = array(
    "firstelement",
    "secondelement",
    "lastelement",
 );  

 next($array); //move to index 1

var_dump(key($array)); //<-- should print 1
foreach( $array as $key => $value ){}
var_dump(key($array));  //<--  NULL (PHP < 7),  1 PHP 7+
```

This outputs ( in PHP7.0.1 )

```
= NATIVE TRACKED POINTER ===================================
int(1)
NULL
= NATIVE ARRAY POINTER =====================================
int(1)
NULL
```

This outputs ( in PHP5.6.29 )

```
= MANUAL TRACKED POINTER ===================================
int(1)
NULL
= NATIVE ARRAY POINTER =====================================
int(1)
NULL
```

Option2:

Make sure to reset the `$position` in `$myIterator->valid()' when the pointer is out of bounds. (This should be done after the call to`valid()`you could check on next, by setting the pointer to`NULL` we can at least emulate the behavior you would get using native pointer tracking )

```
class myIterator implements Iterator {
    private $position = 0;
    private $array = array(
        "firstelement",
        "secondelement",
        "lastelement",
    );  

    public function __construct() {
        $this->position = 0;
    }

    public function rewind() {
        $this->position = 0;
    }

    public function current() {
        return $this->array[$this->position];
    }

    public function key() {
        return $this->position;
    }

    public function next() {
        ++$this->position;
    }

    public function valid() {
        $valid = isset($this->array[$this->position]);

        if(!$valid){
            $this->position = null;
        }

        return $valid;
    }

    public function showPosition() {
        return $this->position;
    }

}

echo str_pad('= MANUAL TRACKED POINTER =', 60, '=') ."\n";

$it = new myIterator;

$it->next(); //move to index 1

var_dump($it->key());   //<-- should print 1

foreach($it as $key => $value) {}

var_dump($it->key()); //<--shows NULL (PHP < 7),

echo str_pad('= NATIVE ARRAY POINTER =', 60, '=') ."\n";

$array = array(
    "firstelement",
    "secondelement",
    "lastelement",
 );  

 next($array); //move to index 1

var_dump(key($array)); //<-- should print 1
foreach( $array as $key => $value ){}
var_dump(key($array));  //<--  NULL (PHP < 7),  1 PHP 7+
```

For Option2, I set it up to reflect the native behavior of PHP < 7, because you are manually tracking the array pointer there is no easy way to do it with just the `Iterator` interface.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2d38af15e5b0269dcdd341d0a77b601ce2713cce

This outputs ( in PHP7.0.1 )

```
= MANUAL TRACKED POINTER ===================================
int(1)
int(0)
= NATIVE ARRAY POINTER =====================================
int(1)
int(1)
```

This outputs ( in PHP5.6.29 )

```
= MANUAL TRACKED POINTER ===================================
int(1)
NULL
= NATIVE ARRAY POINTER =====================================
int(1)
NULL
```

**UPDATE**

Now if you want to fully emulate the behavior of PHP7 it's going to take a lot more work.  ( I am sure there may be other way of doing this, but this is the way I came up with )

```
class myIterator implements IteratorAggregate{
    protected $innerIterator = [];

    public function __construct(array $array = []){
        $this->innerIterator = new myInnerIterator($array,$this);
    }

    public function getIterator(){
        $this->innerIterator->cachePointer();
        return $this->innerIterator;
    }

    public function seek($index){
        $this->innerIterator->seek($index);
    }

    public function rewind() {
        $this->innerIterator->rewind();
    }

    public function current() {
        return $this->innerIterator->current();
    }

    public function key() {
       return $this->innerIterator->key();
    }

    public function next() {
       $this->innerIterator->next();
    }

    public function valid() {
        return $this->innerIterator->valid();       
    }
}

class myInnerIterator implements SeekableIterator{

    protected $array;

    protected $pointer_cache = null;

    public function __construct( array $array = [], $wrapper){
        if( !is_a($wrapper, 'myIterator') ) throw new Exception('myInnerIterator can only be constructed by myIterator');
        $this->array = new ArrayIterator($array);
    }

    public function cachePointer(){
        $this->pointer_cache = $this->key();
    }

    public function seek($index){
        $this->array->seek($index);
    }

    public function rewind() {
        $this->array->rewind();
    }

    public function current() {
        return $this->array->current();
    }

    public function key() {
       return $this->array->key();
    }

    public function next() {
       $this->array->next();
    }

    public function valid() {
        $valid = $this->array->valid();
        if(!$valid && $this->pointer_cache ){
            if( defined('PHP_VERSION_ID') && PHP_VERSION_ID >= 70000 )
                $this->seek( $this->pointer_cache );
            $this->pointer_cache = null;
        }
        return $valid;
    }

}

echo str_pad('= CACHED  POINTER =', 60, '=') ."\n";

$array = array(
    "firstelement",
    "secondelement",
    "lastelement",
); 

$it = new myIterator($array);

$it->next(); //move to index 1

var_dump($it->key());   //<-- should print 1

foreach($it as $key => $value) {}

var_dump($it->key()); //<--shows NULL,

echo str_pad('= NATIVE ARRAY POINTER =', 60, '=') ."\n";

 next($array); //move to index 1

var_dump(key($array)); //<-- should print 1
foreach( $array as $key => $value ){}
var_dump(key($array));  //<--  NULL (PHP < 7),  1 PHP 7+
```

And it outputs

This outputs ( in PHP7.0.1 )

```
= CACHED POINTER ===================================
int(1)
int(1)
= NATIVE ARRAY POINTER =====================================
int(1)
int(1)
```

This outputs ( in PHP5.6.29 )

```
= CACHED POINTER ===================================
int(1)
NULL
= NATIVE ARRAY POINTER =====================================
int(1)
NULL
```

Here is a sandbox where you can test this

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/66dc26003347ec40184bb0283e78a3d67e86c51a

The way this is setup you should never have to touch the `myInnerIterator` class because it's wrapped in `myIterator`, in fact if you try to created it without passing it an instance of myIterator, it will throw an Exception.  The trick is you need `IteratorAggregate::getIterator` Which is called when the `foreach` starts, and then `SeekableIterator::seek`, also the caching of the position has to be done in the InnerIterator.  As far as what else calls `getIterator` automatically and what all that will affect I don't really know off the top of my head.

Anyway hope that helps, or gives you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks. I was confused by the statement that "In PHP 7, foreach does not use the internal array pointer."

Comment: I have no question about adding seekable, what annoying to me is that I (and everyone working on the project) need to remember to save and restore the position before/after all foreach() - this will be a trap for everyone. I wonder why PHP doesn't integrate this within foreach() so that it would change the internal pointer like it promised.

Comment: Actually in 7 the pointer stays at `0`, yours moves because you are increment it.  Basically you are keeping track of the internal pointer yourself, this is why I use either the array functions  `next($array)`, `key($array)` or use an `ArrayIterator`  don't keep track of them yourself

Comment: @LazNiko - you should have question about it.  Then you might not get odd behavior.  Unless I misunderstood

Comment: if not keeping track of $this->position, how would you implement the valid()?  It is supposed to tell whether the current position is valid.

    public function valid() {
        return isset($this->array[$this->position]);
    }

Comment: same way `return isset( $this->array[$this->getKey()] );` but use the array pointer as the index.  and in `getKey(){ return key($this->array); }` And in `next(){ next($this->array); }` and in `rewind(){ reset($this->array)}`

Comment: The value after foreach is based on what you return from `valid()` or so my testing leads me to believe.  If you want to get real picky you could try to return  `0` for PHP7+ and `null` for < PHP7.  You know make it consistent with foreach

Comment: @LazNiko - Updated my answer to include a fix for your original implementation as well as my implementation using the native array functions.

Comment: I copied your class codes in Option 1, PHP shows "call to underfined function valid()"  error for this `return valid( $this->array )`.

Comment: I'm not sure about resetting the position in valid(). Accroding to [the PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/iterator.valid.php) : **Iterator::valid — Checks if current position is valid**. If the position is reset inside this function, it means only the first time of calling will do the checking, and repeat calling of this function will always return true. I think it may give unexpected behavior in some situations.

Comment: PHP7 is not resetting the key to zero in valid(). if your test code with native array, if you advance the internal pointer to 1, after the foreach loop, the key is still kept as 1. Test with these codes `$array = array(
    "firstelement",
    "secondelement",
    "lastelement",
 );  
next($array);  // advance the internal pointer from 0 to 1
var_dump(key($array));  //shows 1
foreach( $array as $key => $value ){}
var_dump(key($array));   // in PHP7, it will show 1 instead of 0`.

Comment: So, I think what PHP7 does is either a) store the array's current internal pointer and after the loop it will restore the internal pointer, or b) just not use the internal pointer at all. In any case, it never reset the internal pointer to any hard-coded value.

Comment: opps, for `valid` it should be `isset($this->array[$this->key()]);`  you could just do `isset($this->array[key($this->array)])` too, I like doing the method, because then if you change something in `$this->key()` you don't have to change `valid()`  in this case it probably doesn't matter much.

Comment: You only reset the pointer if `it's out of bounds` and you still return the failed `either 0, or null`  there is no - unexpected behaviour.

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect that, the best we can do witout more work is make it return what you get using the native array functions which is `null` instead of `3` when manually tracking the pointer.

Comment: @LazNiko - Ok i came up with a way to emulate PHP7s behavior